# web requests and navigation

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

what is the best way \ recommended way to handle the case when user navigates away from an activity while a web request which started in the activity is running?

I was thinking to use a CancellationTokenSource.Token in requests and call CancellationTokenSource.Cancel on Activity's OnPause or OnStop

OnPause will not always work as it can be called even when the activity is obscured. 
I could do the web requests on the OnResume but if I need to do 3 web requests this means all of them will need to re-run just because the activity was partially obscured. I am not sure how good this might look like.

OnStop is better but it might not be called by OS in some conditions

Instead of this, another option I see which could be easier is to just check if activity still exists when the web request returns.